# How can I update a checkbox from a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

I have a plugin that is listening for a form submit.
Within that form are two fields `firstName` and `agreeToTerms`.

When the form is submitted, I am updating an existing entry with the values that were posted.

I can get all fields to update except my checkbox. I'm not sure what I need to send to craft if the user has checked the checkbox.

Here is what I have so far:

**MyController**

```
$postDateTime = ...

...
$entry->setContentFromPost(array(
    'agreeToTerms' => craft()->request->getPost('fields.agreeToTerms'),
    'firstName' => craft()->request->getPost('fields.electronicSignature'),
    'signatureDate' => $postDateTime
));
...
```

This returns "1" which is the value of the checkbox.

```
craft()->request->getPost('fields.agreeToTerms') // returns 1
```

But that isn't what I need to send to Craft. If I were using jquery, I am looking for something like

```
$.prop('checked', true);
```

**EDIT**

To help clarify in case someone else comes across this thread, as @carlcs stated I was in fact talking about a checkbox field.

The plugin I am using allows users to create entries in a section. When an entry is created, one of the fields is a checkbox. I was attempting to set the checkbox field as checked if the user had checked the corresponding checkbox when the entry was created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're talking about a Checkboxes field type. Because you can have multiple checkboxes within such a field, Craft stores an array to the database.

Try if this works:

```
$entry->setContentFromPost(array(
    'agreeToTerms' => array(
        craft()->request->getPost('fields.agreeToTerms'),
    )
));
```

Comment: Thank you both! I knew I needed to pass an array I think I tried every version of `agreeToTerms[]` I could think of...except this one.